# call not sent in Android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I get this note "Call Not Sent" when using the below code in android

[image]

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(callingNumber));
            startActivity(callIntent);
```

why am I getting this note? While I won't get this note when I change *Intent.ACTION_CALL* to *Intent.ACTION_DIAL* which goes to dialpad.

Comment: It won't work on the emulator, just in case that's what you're trying.

Comment: @TomDignan     thanks...but when I call with ACTION_DIAL and then call then the emulator does not show that note.

Comment: Yes its obvious, because you haven't set the phone number to call.

Comment: @PareshMayani I dont know why this is happenning, when I use with ACTION_DIAL it goes to dialpad and when I click call in dialpad then I wont get these note at all...more than this I have another call option where in I use the same code with ACTION_CALL and I wont get any note at all.thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + callingNumber));
startActivity(intent);
```

Notice: `Uri.parse("tel:" + callingNumber)`

Comment: yes I have taken the action about what you have given...thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this:

```
callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

END the previous call you have made from emulator
then it will work fine
according to the image you have called 583-3500 and you have not press the end call button
when you tried to call it again it will not work

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the permission: CALL_PHONE set:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CALL_PHONE
in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I don't see why this deserves a down vote. You didn't mention having the permission in your manifest and the documentation states that this is required to call a number without going through the dialer for a confirmation first, which would seem to fit your problem exactly. While it may not have solved your specific problem it may help others who have a similar problem but simply forgot the permission. I should downvote your question for lacking information but i'm not as much of a jerk as you are.

Comment: ps downvotes should be for misinformation, not answers that didn't solve your problem.. For instance, misinformation in this case would be if I told you to make sure you had a permission that was completely irrelevant or unnecessary to the problem.

Comment: I have not downvoted your response and some other users have downvoted to your response...Why are you asking me that I have done to your response...thanks.